# Pull live streaming Excel data into dataframe

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have an Excel sheet with Live data being streamed on it (every second or less). In order to let the data flowing, the spreadsheet has to be kept open.

I have tried pandas to pull the data from this workbook but this only shows the data when the file was last saved. Is there any way to pull live data from the sheet?

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas

while True:
    df = pandas.read_excel('Data.xlsx',sheetname=0)
    print df['Bid Size'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but I assume that you have an open excel file, and you are making changes without save them.
If so, basically, the answer is no. You have to save your changes if you want to read it with pandas.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this said task without using pandas?

Comment: You have to save your changes before you can read them in other process. Maybe you can find a way to save your changes automatically.
Please describe the process that insert the 'live data' into the excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow a different approach here. The source system is a trading System like Bloomberg, or? The Excel is populated by the external source, probably via plugin. I'd try two approaches: Connect directly to the source system or try to convince Excel to publish ist changes over to Python (via VBA) as soon as the data changes.

Reading the XLS file won't work, as Pandas can only handle it once it is saved.